# Server error when creating a token for Google API

Tags: google-drive-api, authorization, google-oauth

GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframerpc?action=issueToken&response_type=token%20id_token&login_hint=<>&client_id=<>.apps.googleusercontent.com&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&ss_domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000 403

**Uncaught {type: 'tokenFailed', idpId: 'google', error: 'server_error'}**

I used the below code in React.js
https://github.com/willikay11/React-Google-Drive-Tutorial/blob/master/src/Components/SelectSource/index.js#L17

Please help in this...

I have a testing account and API client and Client id is given. The button click prompts for app permission allowing... but then after that it gives this error.

I tried finding where the error was, it doesnt return the access token from google servers. I have added http://localhost as an allowed URL and the redirect URL is the http:localhost:3000/currentpage